# Words of more than 32765 characters

Tags: pdf, strings, viewers

When I compile the following document:

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
\end{document}
```

where the number of x's is greater than 32765, Adobe Reader is not able to read the document anymore, and just produces a blank page. Has anybody come across this before?

Comment: The actual limit seems to be 32767 = 2^{15}-1; other PDF viewers don't choke even with 1073741 characters (Skim on Mac OS X).

Comment: Have you tried different versions of Adobe Reader/Acrobat?

Comment: How the heck did you come across this behavior?

Comment: In the anglophone world, it is standard that the `.` in 32.765 would be interpreted as a decimal point. That is, 32.765 is less than 33. The typical thousands separator is the comma `,`. The numbers here are not so big, so I edited the post to just _remove_ the separator. I believe this is the least ambiguous approach.

Comment: @doncherry Where I work, we use LaTeX for document generation. One of the unit tests produce a very funky report, including such a string. The reason for the string, is actually to test what happens when generating an excel-sheet, where the maximum number of characters in a cell is larger than 32.767.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The implementation limit for the length of strings in content streams for readers on 32-bit architectures is 32767 according to [ISO 32000-2008](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), Table C.1, so 32766 and 32767 should probably also work.

Comment: I tried indeed with `\romannumeral 32767000` to print a string consisting of 32677 m's and Reader opened it; with 32768 it didn't. Probably Reader is enforcing the limit, while other programs don't (see my comment above).

Comment: @egreg: It doesn't have to *enforce* it: the limit is simply the length that any reader *has* to support - it's free to support longer strings, but producers are warned against creating them.

Comment: Said in other words: Adobe people decided to not support longer strings and they have very good reasons.

Comment: @egreg: Well, the implementation limits of 32 bit Adobe software are simply quite old; e.g. floats are limited to singe precision.

Comment: @egreg: Why would Adobe people enforce such limits? What good reasons do you have in mind?

Comment: @CountZero Probably they want to keep adherent to the ISO standard; remember that PDF *is* an ISO standard.

Comment: @CountZero: You seem to believe that Adobe is evil. For a non-evil explanation see my answer above.

Comment: @Martin Schröder: No, I don't. I was just wondering whether adhering strictly to a standard does not raise more issues than it solves. Standards are not perfect, either, like anything else created by man.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Adobe Reader X, it is OK. I think you may need to update your software.

Comment: I used Adobe Reader X myself, and I get the problem.

Comment: Seeing the problem with Acrobat X on Win XP